How to replay fiddler properly
I have a desktop app that makes 20 calls to the web. However 10 calls in it are the same just that these post calls have different parameters.  Each subsequent call is dependent on part of the previous call. I have received the client's problematic scenario fiddler logs. When I looked up the internet, it said I needed to breakpoint and reply for each call.
Since I have a full log is there some industry standard application to replay it on my machine so that I can replay it & solve the customer issue?

Using FiddlerScript you should be more flexible. That way you should be able to send automatic responses and include parameters from previous requests/responses.

This looks like a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, not Stack Overflow
